# Azure active directory JWT Public key changing

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory

Azure AD randomly changes the JWT public token without warning. Am I able to turn the functionality off completely?  I would like the public key to never change.

Answer (score 7):

Azure AD signing keys are rotated on a periodic basis as well as on an immediate basis sometimes.

Please take a look at related Microsoft guidance : [Signing key rollover in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover)

> For security purposes, Azure AD’s signing key rolls on a periodic
>   basis and, in the case of an emergency, could be rolled over
>   immediately. Any application that integrates with Azure AD should be
>   prepared to handle a key rollover event no matter how frequently it
>   may occur. If it doesn’t, and your application attempts to use an
>   expired key to verify the signature on a token, the sign-in request
>   will fail.

In your question you've mentioned `"Am I able to turn the functionality off completely? I would like the public key to never change."`.

You cannot control this behavior, as explained in the documentation above. Your application needs to be designed so that it can handle this key rotation.

You can always get to the latest signing keys using the OpenID Connect discovery document. Look for **`jwks_uri`** value.

You can use common endpoints to get to that information or tenant specific endpoints as well.

```
Azure AD V1 common endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration    
Azure AD V2 common endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Signing Keys can be found at a URL like

```
Azure AD V1 - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys     
Azure AD V2 - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

Again you could use tenant specific endpoint as well, like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/keys
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

The **`kid`** value found for keys here will match with the identifier for key that that has been used for signing the token you receive. This you can check in the token header. Example:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "iBjL1Rcqzhiy4fpxIxdZqohM2Yk",
  "kid": "iBjL1Rcqzhiy4fpxIxdZqohM2Yk"
}
```

On a side note -

1. In case you plan to cache some keys, your app will need to regularly check back for updates and in case of failure, go to endpoint above on demand basis to get the new keys. This Microsoft documentation on [validating the signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-the-signature) mentions that

   > A reasonable frequency to check for updates to the public keys used by
   >   Azure AD is every 24 hours.
2. Many times validating tokens explicitly is not even required since Azure AD middleware has built-in capabilities for validating access tokens.

Comment: "I don't think you would be able to control this" *You cannot control this behaviour.*

Comment: @juunas thanks! good suggestion as always :) I have edited the answer to reflect that.