# How to decode JWT token supplied by Azure oauth using PHP?

Tags: php, azure, jwt

I am completely new to JWT and oAuth but after 8 hours of searching I am stuck. I have this code:

```
<?PHP
    require_once '/home/site/PHP-JWT/vendor/autoload.php';
    use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
    $jwt=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_MS_TOKEN_AAD_ID_TOKEN'];
    $secret_key = "Where_to_find_this";
    $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $secret_key, array('RS256'));
    print_r($decoded);
?>
```

The $jwt variable has a proper token (jwt.io can decode it fine). What should I use for the $secret_key value? I keep reading it should be my Azure (or Azure AD) private key, but I've got no clue where to start looking for this.
Besides: if jwt.io can decode this token without providing it any certificates, how can this be safe?

Comment: Why do you need to manually decode the token?

Comment: *Besides: if jwt.io can decode this token without providing it any certificates, how can this be safe?* - token are signed, not encrypted: [If you can decode JWT, how are they secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27301557)

Comment: *keep reading it should be my Azure (or Azure AD) private key* - you need the public key to **verify** the token. You should find the key in form of a JWK on an endpoint as described here: [Azure active directory JWT Public key changing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58330545)

Comment: @ADyson: I need to decode the token in order to retrieve some additional claims in the token. I need those user-properties for my application to work.

Comment: @jps Thanks for the clarification about the signing. Makes perfect sense. However, if Microsoft will change the public key not only periodically but also on an ad-hoc basis it will include a lot more programming to get that all in place. 
I feel the easier way to fetch the user-properties I need from Azure is through a call to the Graph api. I will abandon the path of decoding JWT tokens.

Comment: I have worked on something similar in Node.js and Python. There should be a way (a JWK Client library) of using the JWKs URI to get public signing keys. For node, I did something like:
`const signing_key = client.getSigningKey(decoded_access_token.header.kid);`
`const publicKey = signing_key.publicKey;`

You can find my full example [here](https://docs.authgear.com/get-started/backend-api/jwt)

Answer (score -1):

To incorporate the required functionality in your code, you need to include the use \Firebase\JWT\Key; statement and use the JWT::decode() method with the appropriate parameters. The updated code snippet below demonstrates the implementation:

```
require_once '/home/site/PHP-JWT/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use \Firebase\JWT\Key;
$jwt=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_MS_TOKEN_AAD_ID_TOKEN'];
$secret_key = "Where_to_find_this";
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($secret_key, 'HS256'));
print_r($decoded);
```

By adding the use \Firebase\JWT\Key; statement, you ensure that the Key class from the JWT library is properly imported and accessible for use. The JWT::decode() method is then utilized to decode the provided JWT token using the new Key($secret_key, 'HS256') as the key.

Comment: did you use chatgpt at all to write any part of this?

Comment: @starball I faced a similar problem and solved it by researching. I shared my solution to help others who might have the same issue.